# Extract the mapping dictionary between two columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below.

df:

```
id      player     country_code   country
1       messi      arg            argentina
2       neymar     bra            brazil
3       tevez      arg            argentina
4       aguero     arg            argentina
5       rivaldo    bra            brazil
6       owen       eng            england
7       lampard    eng            england
8       gerrard    eng            england
9       ronaldo    bra            brazil
10      marria     arg            argentina
```

from the above df, I would like to extract the mapping dictionary that relates the `country_code` with `country` columns.

Expected Output:

```
d = {'arg':'argentina', 'bra':'brazil', 'eng':'england'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary has unique keys, so is possible convert `Series` with duplicated `index` by column `country_code`:

```
d = df.set_index('country_code')['country'].to_dict()
```

If there is possible some `country` should be different per `country_code`, then is used last value per `country`.